# Wordpress, inserting URL in a shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display/insert a url into the shortcode below:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player fileurl="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/my-music/mysong.mp3"]'); ?>
```

I'm using a ACF field called "add_audio" which is a mp3 URL.

I used the default get field ( `<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>` )
code to call the the url.

I made a variable too and called ($variable) too.

But nothing worked!!
Here's the error i get

> "Prase error:syntax error, unexpected 'add_audio'(T_STRING),
>   expecting,''or')'in
>   /app/public/wp-content/oxygen/component-framework/components/layouts/code-block.php(33):eval()'d
>   code on line 43"

I used Oxygenbuilder plugin and ACF plugins.

```
<?php 
/* 
 * Easy Query Shortcode
 * [easy_query container="div" template="template_906184" posts_per_page="20" post_type="audio_files"]
 */
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('audio_files'), 
  'post_status' => 'publish', 
  'order' => 'DESC', 
  'orderby' => 'date', 
  'posts_per_page' => 20, 
  'paged' => $paged, 
);

// WP_Query
$eq_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($eq_query->have_posts()) : // The Loop
$eq_count = 0;
?>
<div class="wp-easy-query paging-style-default grey">
    <div class="wp-easy-query-posts">
        <div>
            <?php 
while ($eq_query->have_posts()): $eq_query->the_post();
$eq_count++;
?>

            <div id="div_block-17-25" class="ct-div-block audio-div">
                <h1 id="headline-18-25" class="ct-headline">
                    <?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div id="div_block-20-25" class="ct-div-block">

<?php echo do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player_template1 fileurl="<?php the_field('add_audio'); ?>"]'); ?>



                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include(EQ_PAGING); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've found a solution to this, so please ignore this post!

Answer (score 1):

Simply Try Removing  from your Code write it as follows:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player_template1 fileurl="'.the_field('add_audio').'"]'); ?>
```